# How to navigate to last line of a series of duplicate/similar lines in vim

Tags: vim

I have a file that has over 100k lines that start with similar words like parsing file or warning. I frequently need to bypass these line and move to texts following them.

How do I navigate to the last lines of such similarly starting lines?

The text is not segmented in paragraphs.

Comment: Guessing that "lines in lacs" is an indian saying for over 100k

Comment: @JamesZ Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for lines that don’t start with things you want to ignore:

```
/^\(parsing file\|warning\)\@!
```

`\@!` is a negative lookahead.